# Как получить содержимое из ipset-таблицы?

Tags: c, gcc, ipset

Использую библиотеку libipset-dev, но не могу понять как правильно вытащить данные (а именно список ip-адресов) из определенной таблицы у ipset.

Например, имеется таблица test. В ней находится:

```
Name: test
Type: hash:ip
Revision: 3
Header: family inet hashsize 1024 maxelem 4000000
Size in memory: 16616
References: 0
Members:
192.168.0.2
192.168.0.1
```

Пишу код на C:

```
ipset_load_types();
session=ipset_session_init(printf);
if (!session) {RETURN_FALSE;}  
ipset_session_data_set(session,IPSET_SETNAME,"test");
if (!ipset_type_get(session,IPSET_CMD_TEST)) {RETURN_FALSE;}
```

Я так понимаю получить данные можно через ipset_session_data_get(session,IPSET_OPT_IP), но не понимаю какой формат отправляет данная функция (по идее должна nf_inet_addr) и как из него отразить (причем каждый элемент/ip, чтобы после занести в отдельный массив).

Может у кого есть уже готовый пример? Спасибо.

Comment: в каком виде хочешь получить данные? если нужны в сишном массиве, то это будет сложно потому как libipset не имеет с-апи и нужно формировать вызовы вручную.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

libipset-dev - ничем не поможет, в заголовочных файлах только то что использует сама ipset. Проще запустить `ipset save test` и распарсить вывод.

Для получения структуры с элементами нужно собрать и вызвать сообщение

```
build_msg(session, NULL);
```

при этом установить

```
session->cmd = IPSET_CMD_LIST
```

Через заголовочные файлы в libipset-dev и динамическую линковку это выполнить не получится. Так как эти методы не предоставленны в заголовочных файлах. А `ipset_session_data_get` не делает запросы к ядру, только разбирает ответ.

Можно выполнить команду

```
ipset_cmd(session, IPSET_CMD_SAVE, 0);
```

которая выдаст

```
add test 192.168.0.1
add test 192.168.0.2
```

в функцию указанную при `ipset_session_init` и там добраться до сырых данных в `ipset_session_handle(session)->data`

Но наверное единственный способ без костылей - передать файл в `ipset_session_io_full` в новой версии ipset.

Если нужен низкий уровень - пишите свои хедеры и переписывайте функции.